# Tomcat 6 is in starting synchronised mode and shutsdown after timeout in eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6

Tomcat logs `INFO: Server startup in 181667 ms` but never in started state as it is in starting and synchronised state. I'm using eclipse Juno. I have gone through related posts but the issue is not resolved.

I get the following error:

> Server Liferay v6.0 CE Server (Tomcat 6) at localhost was unable to start within 900 seconds.
>
> If the server requires more time, try increasing the timeout in the server editor.

Please let know the cause for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can increase your tomcat start time.

Click on double click on on your **server** find **timeout** option and increase your start time (in seconds)

Let me know if you have problem

Comment: hi lucky thanks but this did not solve the problem as sonner or later the timeout expires.i was able to fix this by adding http 8080 port to server.xml .this wasnot set in my tomcat.